# Member access in a doubly-linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently at chapter 17 of Programming: Principles and Practice using C++ and I can't figure something out. In the code below, what does the line 
`norse_gods->succ->prev = norse_gods` actually do? I know that -> is a member access operator, given a pointer to an object. Does it mean that I'm accessing norse_gods successors predecessor? I'm kind of confused with that. This is only the first part, later on in the book an insert operation is defined, which uses the same notation so I'd like to know exactly what it means. Thank you for your time.

Here is the code:

```
struct Link {
string value;
Link* prev;
Link* succ;
Link(const string& v, Link* p = nullptr, Link* s = nullptr)
    : value(v), prev(p), succ(s) {}
};

//insert n before p (incomplete)
Link* insert(Link* p, Link*n)
{
    n->succ = p;
    p->prev->succ = n;
    n->prev = p->prev;
    p->prev = n;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    //Building a list of Norse gods
    //                            val      prev     suc
    Link* norse_gods = new Link{ "Thor", nullptr, nullptr };
    norse_gods =       new Link{ "Odin", nullptr, norse_gods };

    norse_gods->succ->prev = norse_gods;
    norse_gods =       new Link{ "Freya", nullptr, norse_gods };

    norse_gods->succ->prev = norse_gods;


}
```

Comment: `norse_gods->succ->prev` means exactly what you think it means.

Comment: By the way, the `insert` function (which you do not use currently, so why show it?) have a flaw: What if `p` is the first node in the list? Where do `p->prev` then point?

Comment: Oh sorry, I accidently posted the insert function as well. In the next version, there is a check if n and p are nullptrs before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
Link* norse_gods = new Link{ "Thor", nullptr, nullptr };
```

Created a node with a NULL successor and predecessor. Now we attach a second node at the beginning:

```
norse_gods =       new Link{ "Odin", nullptr, norse_gods };
```

Note the previous node in `norse_gods`, Thor, is attached as a successor. So now we have

```
Odin -> Thor
```

But Thor's predecessor pointer is still NULL! We didn't touch it! But we know now it's Odin. So let's fix it to point to Odin, which is currently pointed to by `norse_gods`:

```
norse_gods->successor /*Translates to Odin's successor, which is Thor*/ ->predecessor /*This is still null from the first line*/ = /*So fix it to point to the current norse_gods, Odin*/ = norse_gods /*pointing to Odin*/
```

So now the link is fixed, and Thor's predecessor is Odin, as it should be.