# Pointers and doubly-linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, heap-memory, doubly-linked-list

I am currently on chapter 17 of "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++", and I came across a code on doubly-linked list. Questions have been asked on this set of codes before for (e.g. [Member access in a doubly-linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589999/)), however I have a question that wasn't asked/answered.

The code basically arranges "Freya" as a predecessor of "Odin", and makes "Odin" a predecessor of "Thor", and the other way round as successors. The code is as follows:

```
struct Link {
string value;
Link* prev;
Link* succ;
Link(const string& v, Link* p = nullptr, Link* s = nullptr)
    : value(v), prev(p), succ(s) {}
};

int main()
{
    Link* norse_gods = new Link{ "Thor", nullptr, nullptr };
    norse_gods =       new Link{ "Odin", nullptr, norse_gods };

    norse_gods->succ->prev = norse_gods;
    norse_gods =       new Link{ "Freya", nullptr, norse_gods };

    norse_gods->succ->prev = norse_gods;

}
```

What I would like to know is that why the code:

```
norse_gods =       new Link{ "Odin", nullptr, norse_gods }
```

is able to point to the old address: `new Link{ "Thor", nullptr, nullptr }`, and making Thor the successor of Odin since `norse_god` should already be pointing to the new address: `new Link{ "Odin", nullptr, norse_gods }`? Is there some order or evaluation or concept that I am missing out?

Comment: You are passing `norse_gods` as a parameter to the constructor and then using the "return" value and assigning it to `norse_gods` (replacing whatever value that variable held before)

Comment: Like in `x = x + 5`, the `x` on the left is the "new value", and the `x` on the right is the "old value"

Comment: A side-note is that the formatting of that code is misleading: adding Odin to the list consists of new Link{"Odin", ..} and norse_gods->succ->prev = norse_gods; - and similarly for Freya. Thus if you want a blank lines it would be logical to have them before these group of statements, not in the middle of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The evaluation is first done on the right side and then `operator=` kicks in and does the assignment. This is caused by the priority of `operator=`. See  [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

At the first line of `main`, you are creating a `Link` with name "Thor" and pointing `norse_gods` to it.

At the second line, you are creating a `Link` with name "Odin" and a successor `norse_god`, which is still pointing at Thor at the moment of construction.

After that, `norse_gods` is updated to point to "Odin".

This behavior is normal for C-like languages.

Answer (score 2):

The expression on the right-hand side is evaluated first. This evaluates taking the old value of `norse_gods`. Once this evaluation is complete, the assignment is done, and the reference to the newly created object is assigned to `norse_gods`.

Comment: rvalue is not connected with that on which side of the operator= the expression is. Talking about rvalue references here is inappropriate.

Comment: There is no rvalue references here.